# Tuning NFS: Identifying source of getattr requests

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, tuning

we run some Linux NFS clients against a NetApp NFS storage system. Currently we have over 50% getattr requests running against the NetApp using up precious CPU cycles.

Using the netapp-top.pl script we identified the hosts causing high number of NFS operations.

On the Linux NFS Client we used nmon to identify the type of NFS operations (using 'N' option).

Using the nocto and the actimeo mount option on per Linux client dedicated shares we were already able to reduce the number of NFS getattr requests.

But we have one Linux NFS client where we are not able to identify the mount causing the getattr requests.

How can we identify the mountpoint and possibly the process causing those getattr NFS operations?

Is there a way to identify the getattr requests running against the NetApp on the NetApp itself - like a top list of files being accessed using getattr?

Thanks

Rainer